# can not create new Android project using Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I am trying to create Android project using Android studio.

I have installed the latest Android studio and update it using the `help-check for updates`.

Then I tried to create my first Android project, however after the studio download the `gradle`, it throw a error:

```
Gradle: A problem occurred configuring project ':FirstAndroid'.
> Failed to notify project evaluation listener.
   > Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':FirstAndroid:_DebugCompile'.
      > Could not find any version that matches com.android.support:appcompat-v7:+.
        Required by:
            FirstAndroidProject:FirstAndroid:unspecified
```

I am not sure what's the problem.

Anyone can do me a favor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It says `com.android.support:appcompat-v7` -- maybe, you need to install v7 support?

I have to note that the last time I needed to create a new project, I found the tools in a poor state: to create a project that could compile from both Eclipse and command line I had to create two new projects and manually copy files from one to another (otherwise I was getting a crazy error about null returning 1).

Comment: there's no need to create a new project and start copying files around. Just update the Android SDK that is bundled in Android Stuidio as @hguser has stated. To update go to `Tools-> Android-> SDK Manager`

Answer (score 2):

I am sorry , I think I made a mistake before I ask this questions.

Before using Android studio , I have used eclipse and Idea together with a standalone Android sdk while this sdk cover almost all the required components.

However when I install Android studio, it use  its internal sdk which do not include the components like `com.android.support:appcompat-v7`, after update the sdk through the Android studio, the problem is solved.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same message. (Working on Mac, Android Studio 0.4.5)

Simply updating the SDK through the SDK Manager did correct the issue for me.

To correct the issue I opened the SDK manager (tools -> Android -> SDK Manager).  Scrolled down to the bottom and found the **Extras** folder.

Downloading and installing the components in the Extras folder corrected the issue.